# How is it possible to dynamically cast to a Type that is named in a string with Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, casting, swift2, dynamic-typing

I need to cast a return value to a specific type that I need to keep dynamic, like

```
let cellType = "CellTypeToBeResolved"
cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myID") as? CellTypeToBeResolved)!
```

How is this possible in Swift 2.0?
Thnx!

Comment: You can't, and the fact that you think you need to is a Bad Smell. You can enlist Cocoa / Objective-C to do this for you, of course, but a pure Swift solution is impossible, as this sort of dynamism/introspection is completely opposed to the nature and spirit of Swift.

Comment: thank you. maybe you are right. maybe I just want to shorten too much code.

Comment: I have so many different tableviewcells - too bad...

Comment: My thought here is: step back a couple of steps and describe the underlying problem and let's talk about how to solve _that_ problem. Like, you've got several cell types in your table? I would say delete this q. and describe that. I think you'll find we can work out something nice with a `switch` statement or similar.

Comment: Of course if you really want me to I can answer your question with a little lecture about why Swift stops you from doing what you described, but it hardly seems worth while. :)

Comment: Sorry, gave you the lecture anyway. Feel free to delete the question, though, I won't be offended. :)

Comment: That is not a problem for me. I like to ask stupid questions . :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do it, because Swift is (deliberately) missing not one but two pieces of the puzzle:

- You can't turn a string into a class.
- More important, you can't cast down to a class expressed as a variable. The class to cast down to must be a literal class, i.e. it must be known at compile time. The compiler needs to know that this cast is legal, plus it needs to know at compile time how to treat this variable. If you want to be able to send MyCoolTableCell instance messages to this cell, you need to use the literal MyCoolTableCell name in your code — not a string, not a variable containg the type, but the type *itself*.

Comment: great, thank you. I leave this questions for other recent scripters that used languages before where this kind of sloppy programming was possible.

Comment: Couldn't you do this (assuming the classes inherit from NSObject) using Cocoa runtime calls? (Not arguing that you should, but wouldn't it be possible?)

Comment: @DuncanC Not in Swift, not easily. You'd need to write this part of your code _in Objective-C_. Sure, you can make Cocoa calls to turn a string into  a class, but you can't do anything more with it than you could have done with e.g. `MyCoolTableCell.self` in a variable — you still can't cast to it _in Swift_.

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSClassFromString to convert your string to the class you want, then you can use that to cast the tableviewCell

Comment: That doesn't work.  Using a returned class type after the `as` results in a precompiler error.