# instantiate ViewController and cast it to class from string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have array of strings

```
var arr = ["firstViewController", "secondViewController", ....]
```

For each of it's items I need to instantiate ViewController like

```
var myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as! firstViewController
```

If i want to instantiate View Controllers from loop I need to make class from string but this code

```
let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String
let cls: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(className)")!
```

Is not working

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32265287/308315) solution posted on a similar StackOverflow question?

Comment: _Why_ do you need this? You could just instantiate the controllers in a loop as `UIViewController`s and then try to downcast when needed...

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you cannot cast to a runtime type object. Swift knows  the types of all of its variables at its compile time.

Now you have a variable, whose value is some type that the compiler knows nothing about, so the compiler cannot let you do anything with variable for type cast.

Reference:- [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554789/dynamic-casting-using-result-of-nsclassfromstringmyuiviewcontroller?answertab=oldest#tab-top), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094293/how-is-it-possible-to-dynamically-cast-to-a-type-that-is-named-in-a-string-with?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `NSClassFromString(_:)` to instantiate a `UIViewController` from a loop. You were headed in the right direction in your first two lines of code:

```
let nameArray = ["firstViewController", "secondViewController" /*....*/]
var controllerArray = [UIViewController?]()

for name in nameArray {
    controllerArray.append(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name))
}
```